# Unable to upload video in laravel, error message "given data was invalid"

Tags: laravel-5, file-upload

I can not upload video files more than 2 mb in my project. I'm receiving `error 422, error message : the given data was invalid` and the file failed to upload.

I raised `post_max_size` and `upload_max` size in `php.ini`, but that did not work.
I can upload files smaller than 2 mb.